# How can I achieve proxy configuration similar to a corporate environment?

Tags: proxy, home-networking

At my work we have a proxy setup where no computers can leave the internal network without using a proxy. We use WPAD to determine which proxy to use, but how can something like this be set up in my home network?

If I have 6 PCs, 4 laptops, a few smartphones, etc, how can I make it so none of them can use the internet if they aren't going through a proxy? I have a router and a cable modem that comprise the backbone of my home network, so I'm curious as to how this could be made possible.

Answer (score 0):

Look in to a linux disto called "Smoothwall" or "PFSense" (There are also many others).

My preference is [Smoothwall](http://www.smoothwall.org/).  You can also install add-ons to improve it's functionality if you find something is lacking.

You basically download the .iso for smoothwall, install it on a spare box you have lying around (by the sounds of things, this shouldn't be too hard to come by).  The box should have two Network cards in it.  One NIC will connect to your router, the other will connect to your LAN.

No other computers should connect to the router.  They should connect to the LAN, and Smoothwall will become your LAN's new router, using your EXISTING router by itself to get to the internet.